# how to resolve:- PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: begin end function pragma procedure

Tags: sql, oracle

Need to alter the table by adding one column how can we write correct syntax for altering the table inside the package? it can be with procedure or function?

I tried with procedure and getting this error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY temp IS

  PROCEDURE prc_proc_add_column(
                                 table_name  IN user_tab_columns.TABLE_NAME%TYPE,
                                 p_return    OUT NUMBER,
                                 p_message   OUT VARCHAR2
                               ) IS   
  BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE table_name ADD col_name NUMBER';
     p_return  := 0;
     p_message := 'Succesful';
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN p_return  := SQLCODE;
                               p_message := SQLERRM;        
  END prc_proc_add_column;
```

then getting this error:-

> ```
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of      
> the following: begin end function pragma procedure
> ```

Comment: Does the package body end with an `END;`?

Comment: no, that package name is different , for now i'm just making procedure and if it runs good then i'll add in package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barbaros already commented what is wrong with code you posted, as far as syntax is concerned.

---

Sure, you can do it, but - generally speaking - it isn't the best idea to modify data model *dynamically*.

When you're here, why wouldn't you modify that code so that you could provide not only table name, but also column name and its datatype?

Note that - when using dynamic SQL on DDL statements - you have to concatenate names into the statement; you can't use bind variables (not that you did ...), and - again generally speaking - it wouldn't hurt if you take care about possible SQL injection.

Here's an example.

Package specification:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE temp
  2  IS
  3     PROCEDURE prc_proc_add_column (
  4        p_table_name   IN     user_tab_columns.table_name%TYPE,
  5        p_column_name  IN     user_tab_columns.column_name%TYPE,
  6        p_datatype     IN     user_tab_columns.data_type%TYPE,
  7        p_return          OUT NUMBER,
  8        p_message         OUT VARCHAR2);
  9  END;
 10  /

Package created.
```

Package body:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY temp
  2  IS
  3     PROCEDURE prc_proc_add_column (
  4        p_table_name   IN     user_tab_columns.table_name%TYPE,
  5        p_column_name  IN     user_tab_columns.column_name%TYPE,
  6        p_datatype     IN     user_tab_columns.data_type%TYPE,
  7        p_return          OUT NUMBER,
  8        p_message         OUT VARCHAR2)
  9     IS
 10        l_str  VARCHAR2 (200);
 11     BEGIN
 12        l_str :=
 13              'ALTER TABLE '
 14           || DBMS_ASSERT.sql_object_name (p_table_name)
 15           || ' ADD '
 16           || DBMS_ASSERT.simple_sql_name (p_column_name)
 17           || ' '
 18           || DBMS_ASSERT.simple_sql_name (p_datatype);
 19
 20        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_str;
 21
 22        p_return := 0;
 23        p_message := 'Succesful';
 24     EXCEPTION
 25        WHEN OTHERS
 26        THEN
 27           p_return := SQLCODE;
 28           p_message := SQLERRM;
 29     END prc_proc_add_column;
 30  END;
 31  /

Package body created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE test
  2  (
  3     id   NUMBER
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_ret  VARCHAR2 (200);
  3     l_msg  VARCHAR2 (200);
  4  BEGIN
  5     temp.prc_proc_add_column ('test',
  6                               'salary',
  7                               'number',
  8                               l_ret,
  9                               l_msg);
 10     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_ret || ': ' || l_msg);
 11  END;
 12  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> desc test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER
 SALARY                                             NUMBER

SQL>
```

Comment: It worked . Thanks for this explantion